# How to send paged list livedata from MainActivity to Fragment and make it persist

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, pagedlist

**Issue**

I have a paged list live data source and want to send it to from a MainActivity to a fragment while it should persist during fragment replace.

I've used a viewmodel which is preferred method to ensure persistence throughout the layout changes, however cant send it from Main Activity to Fragment

```
Main Activity


itemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ItemViewModel.class);
```

```
Fragment

itemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity).get(ItemViewModel.class);

 itemViewModel.itemPagedList.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<Item> items) {
                itemsAdapter.submitList(items);

            }
        });
```

**EDIT**
OnBackPressed from another fragment back to the list fragment causes the recycler view list to be blank with no items.

Comment: what can't you send from your activity to your fragment? The code looks okay, it will correctly bind the viewmodel to lifecycle of the activity

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Comment: the Fragment and the activity will share the same instance of  your ItemViewModel. Code look ok on ViewModel, if you are not receiving data on fragment from the activity, i guess it's related to liveData publish implementation issue.

Comment: It looks like UI issue rather than livedata issue.

Comment: How do you send data?

Comment: Clearly the problem is that the fragment adapter view etc setup is in the wrong lifecycle callback method (for example `onActivityCreated()`), but you are not actually showing that in your question.